# text style in EditText Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a login page with 2 `EditText` and a login `Button`.

The code is like this:-

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditText_username"
    ...
    android:hint="@string/username"
    android:inputType="text"
    ...
    android:maxLength="9"
    android:maxLines="1" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditText_password"
    ...
    android:hint="@string/password"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button_login"
    ...
    android:text="@string/login" />
```

I have an android hint on Username `EditText` and on Password `EditText`.
My problem is when the page shows on the emulator, the hints on username and password come in different styles, which is extremely irritating.
Here's a screenshot of the problem -

http://i49.tinypic.com/261lzli.png

Notice Username is in system font and Password in monochrome.
How do I make both of them same?! Either monochrome / system font, both are fine.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd suggest you to use TextViews above the EditTexts with captions "Login" and "Password". This way you'll solve your problem and provide a better user experience: a TextView will always be visible to the user, and hints will disappear as soon as user enters characters in the EditText.

Comment: I dont know why but I feel the UI gets cluttered with too many `TextView`s and `EditText`s. So I would rather use hints so the person knows what he's typing anyways. and these 2 fields are so obvious, u cant mistake one with the other :)

Comment: do u try this apk in phone..

Comment: yup I've tested it on 2 phones and 1 emulator. Same problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following in your `onCreate()` method:

```
EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText_password);  
password.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT); 
password.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
```

Comment: Nope. That's not the case. The problem arises because I think the password field has to be monochrome style because I've specified "inputType = textPassword" in password's `EditText`. If i give focus to `Button` it really doesnt solve the problem because focus is not the problem here..

Comment: Try the following in your `onCreate` method:  EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText_password);
        password.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
        password.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());

Comment: Yes! Works perfect! Can you just put this TypeFace thing in ur answer by editing it? I will accept it as soon as you do that! Thanks a lot! Cheers!